# How to stop program after putting negative value in C

Tags: c

I am little bit lost over here. I did a program in C which do grading but im not sure how to keep the program open until I put a negative value (-4 for example). I am not sure if I have to change int to char. But to me its not it. I just don't know how to keep the program up until the negative value.
Thats the program I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>



int main()

{

int a;

while(a --> 13)
{  

scanf("%d", &a);

if(a<0)
{
    break;
}
else if(a > 100)
{
    printf("NA \n");
    continue;
}
else if(a >=86 && a <=100)
{
    printf("1 \n");
    continue;
}
else if(a >= 61 && a <=85)
{
    printf("2 \n");
    continue;
}
else if(a >= 51 && a <= 60)
{
    printf("3 \n");
    continue;
}
else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
{
    printf("4 \n");
    continue;
    
}
scanf("%d \n", &a);
return 0;

}
}
```

I change it like this but it still doesn't work like it should be..:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;

while (a)
{

if(a>=86 && a<=100)
{
    printf("1 \n");
}
else if(a >= 61&& a <=85)
{
    printf("2 \n");
}
else if(a >= 51&& a <=60)
{
    printf("3 \n");
}
else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
{
    printf("4 \n");
}
else if (a>100)
{
    printf("NA \n");
}
else if (a<0)
{
    break;
}
scanf("%d",&a);
}

}
```

neither like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
int a;

while (a<0)
{
  break;
}
if(a>=86 && a<=100)
{
    printf("1 \n");
}
else if(a >= 61&& a <=85)
{
    printf("2 \n");
}
else if(a >= 51&& a <=60)
{
    printf("3 \n");
}
else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
{
    printf("4 \n");
}
else if (a>100)
{
    printf("NA \n");
}

scanf("%d",&a);


}
```

In this case. The program doesn't stop but works only for first input, then it does nothing

```
int main()

{
int a;
do
{
scanf("%d",&a);
if(a>=86 && a<=100)
{
    printf("1 \n");
}
else if(a >= 61 && a <=85)
{
    printf("2 \n");
}
else if(a >= 51 && a <=60)
{
    printf("3 \n");
}
else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
{
    printf("4 \n");
}
else if (a>100)
{
    printf("NA \n");
}

scanf("%d",&a);

} while (a>0);

}
```

Comment: Hint 1: Proper indentation will make it easier to follow the control flow.  Hint 2: I don't think you need or want all those `continue` statements.  Hint 3: You definitely don't want that `return 0` statement where it is.  Hint 4: Not related to your question, but it's a good idea to check `scanf`'s return value, so your program doesn't go crazy if the user types something that `scanf` can't scan.

Comment: 5: `int a; while(a --> 13)` makes the program read an uninitialized variable (`a`) so the program has undefined behavior

Comment: @TedLyngmo so what should I type in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a do...while cycle, for example:

```
do {
    /* read a and do stuff */

} while (a > 0);
```

Or a while cycle

```
/* read a */
while(a > 0) {
    /* do stuff */
    /* read a */
}
```

EDIT: fix of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;
   
    /* read a before the cycle */
    if(scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (a > 0)
    {
        if(a>=86 && a<=100)
        {
            printf("1 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 61 && a <=85)
        {
            printf("2 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 51 && a <=60)
        {
            printf("3 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
        {
            printf("4 \n");
        }
        else if (a>100)
        {
            printf("NA \n");
        }

        /* update the vaule of a */
        if(scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

do..while solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a;      

    do
    {
        if(scanf("%d",&a) != 1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "scanf fail!\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if(a>=86 && a<=100)
        {
            printf("1 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 61 && a <=85)
        {
            printf("2 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 51 && a <=60)
        {
            printf("3 \n");
        }
        else if(a >= 0 && a<= 50)
        {
            printf("4 \n");
        }
        else if (a>100)
        {
            printf("NA \n");
        }
    } while (a > 0);
}
```

Comment: I did the while cycle as you can see down bellow in my question. still nothing

Comment: You have to read a (scanf) also before the while cycle (1st code example), you have to implement a cycle while a is > 0 (second example)

Comment: I like the do..while solution. Only problem is this: 12.c:10:13: error: implicitly declaring library function 'exit' with type 'void (int) __attribute__((noreturn))' [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            ^
12.c:10:13: note: include the header <stdlib.h> or explicitly provide a declaration for 'exit'
12.c:10:18: error: use of undeclared identifier 'EXIT_FAILURE'
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

Comment: same problem with while solution

Comment: yeah sorry, forgot to add: #include <stdlib.h>

Comment: Your're welcome!